# Is there any idiom to get the identity element (0,1) for an operation (:+,:*) on a Ruby object?

Tags: ruby

Given a certain object that `respond_to? :+` I would like to know what it's the identity element for that operation on that object. For example, if `a` is `Fixnum` then it should give `0` for operation `:+` because `a + 0 == a` for any `Fixnum`. Of course I already know the identity element for `:+` and `:*` when talking about `Fixnum`s, but is there any standard pattern/idiom to obtain those dynamically for all Numeric types and operations?.

More specifically I have write some code (see below) to calculate shortest path between v1 and v2 (vertexes in a graph) where the cost/distance/weigh of each edge in the graph is given in a user-specified type. In the current implementation the cost/weight of the edges could be a `Fixnum`, a `Float` or anything that implements `Comparable` and can add `0` to itself and return `self`.

But I was wondering what is the best pattern:

- requiring that type used must support `a + 0 == a`
- requiring that type provide some kind of addition identity element discovery 'a.class::ADDITION_IDENTITY_ELEMENT
- ??

My [Dijkstra algorithm implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

```
  def s_path(v1,v2)
    dist = Hash.new { nil}
    pred = {}
    dist[v1] = 0 # distance from v1 to v1 is zero
    #pq = nodes 
    pq = [v1]

    while u = pq.shift
      for edge in from(u)
        u,v,cost = *edge
        new_dist = cost + dist[u]  
        if dist[v].nil? or new_dist < dist[v]
          dist[v] = new_dist
          pred[v] = u
          pq << v
        end
      end
    end
    path = [v2]
    path << pred[path.last] while pred[path.last]
    path.reverse
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `a.class::ADDITION_IDENTITY_ELEMENT` is pretty good except I would call it `a.class::Zero`.

Another option would be to do `(a-a)`.

Personally I wouldn't try to make things so abstract and I would just require that every distance be a `Numeric` (e.g. `Float` or `Integer`).  Then you can just keep using `0`.